# How to specify 2 different positions for Colorbox on the same page?

Tags: css, position, colorbox

I'm building a page that has two Colorboxes.

Right now, I've managed to make any Colorbox in general to appear in a fixed position by adjusting the colorbox.css file:

> #colorbox, #cboxOverlay {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
>   #cboxWrapper { position:fixed; margin:0 auto; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden; right:0; top:18px;}

However, I'd really like to be able to position my two Colorboxes separately. My train of thought for this is to have two different CSS (e.g. colorbox.css and colorbox2.css) and make adjustments accordingly, but how do I tell which Colorbox to follow which CSS file?

I'm kinda between beginner and intermediate levels if that makes sense, so it'd be great if anybody could help me out with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add a class for one colorbox and override position rules for this class.

Comment: you mean like this: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".popupa").colorbox({iframe:true, transition:"fade", width:500, height:500, open:true, position:"fixed", right:55});
  $(".popupb").colorbox({iframe:true, transition:"fade", width:375, height:800});  
 });
</script>

i tried that before and doesn't seem to work. maybe i didn't do it right?

Comment: I can't see any class added? It seems to me JQuery provide an "addClass" function.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'm really not familiar with the addClass function. Should it be like this:  

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".popupa").colorbox({iframe:true, transition:"fade", width:500, height:500, open:true});
  $(".colorbox").addClass("testing");
  $(".popupb").colorbox({iframe:true, transition:"fade", width:375, height:800});  
 });

It still doesn't seem to work, though.

Comment: Doesn't the first colorbox have a "testing" class ?

Comment: yes, i just added that, but it doesn't seem to override position rules. i'll try and tweak my code again, i must've gone wrong somewhere. thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to setup the colorboxed with different arguments

```
$(".colorbox1").each(function(i) {
    $(this).colorbox({top:200});
});

$(".colorbox2").each(function(i) {
    $(this).colorbox({top:100});
});
```